# templateUrl works but $templateCache.get doesn't?

Tags: angularjs

If I visit

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/templates/hippo
```

I get a page displaying the following:

```
hungry hungry hippos
```

If I create a hippo directive with two simple get calls to get the same template, something weird happens.

```
.directive 'hippo', ($templateCache)->
    templateUrl: 'templates/hippo'
    console.log $templateCache.get('templates/hippo')
```

Firstly, `hungry hungry hippos` appears on the page inside the `<div hippo></div>` element, but for some weird reason the log of `$templateCache.get('templates/hippo')` is always always undefined.

Does anyone know what could cause this? My routing is being provided by rails. Here's a server log of the page load:

```
Started GET "/templates/hippo" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-03 17:16:41 +0000
Processing by ApplicationController#template as HTML
  Parameters: {"name"=>"hippo"}
  Rendered templates/hippo.html (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 2.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

That GET is referring to `templateUrl`, and yet `$templateCache.get('templates/hippo')` doesn't seem like it interfaces at all with my server...

What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

first you need to put the template into `$templateCache` in `run` stage and then you can get. [Refer this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache)

if you don't want to explicitly put them in `run` stage for some reason, you can use `grunt-angular-templates` in your building stage. also there is one for gulp.
[this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-templates) and 
[this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templates) will also help you

Comment: Okay, but what happens if a have thousands of templates (hypothetically speaking). Would they all need to be included in the `run` stage? Wouldn't that swamp the client? How do we only load templates when we need them? By using templateUrl? Does the client still cache templates served through templateUrl?

Comment: by 'need' you mean when directive is being compiled? i don't think the template will go `$templateCache` when `templateUrl` is used.

Comment: Sorry yeah, when it's being compiled.